# Sketch: Is there a way to use overrides and have text wrapping to push content down?

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

This is the original Symbol. 
[image]

I want to add more text to the 'Stage 13' override and have all elements below be pushed down. However this is what I get:
[image]

What can I do to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I don't know of any vertical resizing, but horizontal resizing in symbols can work with grouped text elements. Usually, it works by pinning the text areas to the desired side (right or left). With this done, and a bit of testing, stretching the symbol should allow you to add text.

Vertical text resizing would be a great future addition, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install plugin called Anima (https://www.animaapp.com/)

Second, you need to watch a gif :)

[image: push the tempo]

Answer (score -2):

This will help you with that quest: https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/overrides-dynamic-buttons-in-sketch-c9ccfb6a5682
It explains how you can use the 'Auto Layout' plugin to make this behavior happen.

[image]

Also the new and improved resize tool can help you with this job.
More info about at one you can find at https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/layer-basics/constraints/

But, this is necessary anymore, Sketch improved of the editions and it is all baked in. It is called Smart Layout. More on this you can find on the site of the makers https://www.sketch.com/features/smart-layout

Comment: Hi Patrick, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. What is the best option now? Edit the post, or reply to it?

Comment: Hitting [edit] and adding additional information is your best bet. Replies on this site are only possible as comments (we're not Reddit :) ) and those are only intended to be temporary. Thanks!